# Using Sticks and Stones for Counting number of Ways

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving, multisets

From the first twenty positive integers, how many ways can we select 6 integers so that no two integers from the six chosen ones are consecutive?

I tried using sticks and stones, but my thought process kept running out of gas and I can't see to get on track.

Comment: It would be inefficient, but you could always build the tree diagram of the situation. First, there are $20$ ways you could pick the first number. Then there are two cases: that first number is $1$ or $20$ and has one neighbor, or that first number has two neighbors. In the first case ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There will be $14$ integers not chosen. Write down $14$ occurrences of $\times$, like this:
$$\times \quad\times\quad\times \quad\times\quad\times \quad\times\quad\times \quad\times\quad\times \quad\times\quad\times \quad\times\quad\times \quad\times$$
These determine $15$ gaps, $13$ real ones plus $2$ endgaps. We must **choose** $6$ of these to slip a Y (yes) into. There is a natural one to one correspondence between the strings of length $20$ made up of $14$ $\times$ and $6$ Y, with no two Y consecutive, and the valid choices. (Number the elements of the string from the left.) The number of ways is therefore $\binom{15}{6}$.

Comment: Wait, how do you know the numbers in the gaps aren't consecutive? The numbers for X are not fixed.

Comment: No, they are not fixed, they are determined from left to right. For example $\times$ Y $\times$ $\times$ Y means $1$ was not chosen, $2$ was chosen, $3$ and $4$ were not chosen, $5$ was chosen (and so on).

Answer (score 2):

The number of ways to select $r$ integers from $(1\ldots n)$ with no two consecutive integers selected is 
$$
\binom{n+1-r}{r}$$

So the answer to your problem is 
$$
\binom{15}{6}= 5005
$$